# ViewPager with swipable indicator

Tags: android, viewpagerindicator

I need a viewPager that can page on about 60 image and I need an indicator.

i'm develoaping a comic reader. i want the inidcator to change for example 10 image in one touch, somthing like what the android gallery has, it is a line of image that are fading to each other and when you touch a part of it it shows that image in small size and when you leave the touch navigate to that picture.

is there any open libary for this type of indicators

thanks

Answer (score 0):

Your question is too general to answer, first you should implement a ViewPager then you can use **Jake Wharton** Library [Android-ViewPagerIndicator](https://github.com/JakeWharton/Android-ViewPagerIndicator)

Comment: i have the viewPager my problem is the indicator, the JakeWharton does not support swipable inidcator such az a line of images in the image gallery

Comment: so i think that library would help you, follow instruction on the link, i implement it's library but didn't check the swipable indicator, so i think you have to change the library yourself to implement such behavior.i don't know any other library with swipeable indicator.

Comment: so witch type of it's indicators should i use ? i have used JakeWharton in some other application and i'm familiar with it

Comment: @VahidHaratian : i've used line indicator before under my gallery so the height of indicator was so small and when you touch the indicator you would touch the ViewPager too , so it sense like swiping Indicator.

Comment: i'm develoaping a comic reader. i want the inidcator to change for example 10 image in one touch, somthing like what the android gallery have, it is a line of image that are fading to each other and when you touch a part of it it shows that image in small size and when you leave the touch navigate to that picture

Comment: @VahidHaratian : sounds interesting but i didn't implement that , i think you can achieve that behavior with playing with the library but i don't have any source code or example for that